# Flexbox problems - Mobile First to iPad design

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

So I have created the mobile site and that looks great but now I'm recoding the css for the ipad resolution. The mobile site has been laid out similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/7UZm3/

**Html**

```
<body>
<div class="box b1">Box One</div>
<div class="box b2">Box Two</div>
<div class="box b3">Box Three</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
display:flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
height:400px;
}
.box {    flex:1;    }
.b1 {    background-color: green;    }
.b2 {    background-color: yellow;    }
.b3 {    background-color: pink;    }
```

But what I want is for box 1 to span the whole height of the screen, and box 2 and 3 aligned to the right of box 1. (so that box 1 has a row span of 2 really)

I can't quite figure out what property needs to be set.
Thanks for any help =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate wrapper for boxes 2 and 3. And then combine `flex-flow: column wrap` with `flex-flow: row wrap`. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UZm3/4/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works, buuuttt ... is there a way to do this without a wrapper? Surely it's possible to have box 1 span the other 2 boxes without additional html?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry.